# Simplify factorials into a combinatorial formula

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, factorial

Is there any way to simplify this into a combinatorial formula?

$$\frac{t!(n-t)!}{n!}$$

Comment: It's the inverse of $n$ choose $t$.

Comment: @user14982305: The use of the word inverse here may be slightly confusing. I think 'multiplicative inverse' or 'reciprocal' would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient, assuming $0 \le t \le n$:

$$ \frac{t!(n-t)!}{n!} = \binom{n}{t}^{-1} $$